# Values not saving and showing on index page in rail app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

New to rails so I am implementing a basic app.

Text field and a submit button, on clicking the submit button the text to be displayed on the div placed below the submit button of the index page.

Code and things I trying is as follows -

Siteurl - `http://localhost:3000/lists/index`

list controller code -

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  List.all
  end

  def add
  @message = params[:todo_text]
  List.create(:title => @message)
  redirect_to '/lists/index', :notice => "Notice"
  end
end
```

Model list.rb -

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title
end
```

Views list index.html.erb code -

```
<div id="search">
<%= form_tag("/lists/add", :method=>"post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:todo_text, '',:class=>"formtext" ) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Add Message", :class=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Now when I submit some text it redirects to the same..but data is not reverting back to the page. Let me know what I am doing wrong and how do i fix it ?

Comment: @anonymousxxx ok..let me trty this code chunk and tell u the output/result then

Comment: @anonymousxxx Throwing this error http://imgur.com/gPBafCo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in controller**

```
def index
  @lists = List.all
end
```

**in index.html.erb**

```
<% @lists.each do |list| %> 
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: i tried this way but not working :( Throwing this error -  NoMethodError in ListsController#add

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "tes":String

Comment: fixed on my own..but ur solution helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= form_for @list, :url => { :action => "add" } do |f| %>
```

controller

```
def index
@lists = List.all
end

def add
      @list = List.new(params[:title])
      redirect_to @lists, :notice => "Notice"
    end
```

Comment: :multipart => true is not required here, there is no file_field in the form